Can high intensity laser excite surface plasma waves?
As we know, light in free space cannot excite plasma waves.
However, it is possible to get help from the prism, grating or surface modification. However, with the help of two high-intensity laser beams that radiate the carbon nanotube, terahertz radiation can be produced through nonlinear effects and generation of nonlinear current density and frequency difference generation. Is the mechanism of terahertz radiation here the excitation of plasma surface waves or are the physics of these two mechanisms (the occurrence of nonlinear effects and the excitation of plasma waves) different?

Are ypu talking about plasma as state of matter or plasmons as excitations of the electron gas? What you describe sounds a lot like the latter, but you do not use the respective terms, which leads to confusion.
exciting plasmons is certainly feasible with laser radiation, see e.g. the fluorescence and absorbance of metal nano particles.

This is rather too broad to be answerable. You mention "the" carbon nanotube, but it's not really clear what situation you are thinking about. You clearly have some context in mind, but if you don't point to it, it will be quite hard to answer the text of the question in a way that matches what you're actually thinking about.

In addition, there is a fair degree of subjectiveness to the last part of the question. What does it really mean for two mechanisms to be 'the same' or 'different'?
